# Returning reference to data memeber in cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What I know, returning a reference to a local variable is the same as returning pointer to local variable and this causes memory leak in C++.

But does this apply to data members?

The code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::string& getId();
private:
    std::string id;
};

MyClass std::string& getId()
{
    return id;
}


int main()
{
    MyClass* c = new MyClass;
    std::string brokenRef = c->getId();
    // or may be std::string& brokenRef = c->getId();
    delete c;

    cout << brokenRef << endl; // <<< this should be a ref to unknown location, correct?

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: While at the machine code level it no difference between a reference and a pointer, it is how they are handled by the compiler. And no memory leak will happen just because you return a reference since nothing is dynamically allocated.

Comment: Just adding to @JoachimPileborg's comment, returning a reference(or a pointer) to a local variable will cause undefined behaviour as you will dereference an address to memory that was already deleted. But will not cause memory leaks directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it applies. Even though your MyClass instance is not strictly local to main, but dynamically allocated and deallocated before the reference. Has the same effect, though.

The code as it stands is correct, because you copy the string while it is valid. The commented-out reference version is truly a broken reference.

Answer (score 1):

In line

```
std::string brokenRef = c->getId();
```

You create a new instance of string and intialize it with a string referenced by reference returned by getId(). From this point on `brokenRef` lives completely independent life from `MyClass` object. Therefore `brokenRef` happily outlived `MyClass` object you destroyed.

You could have achieved desired affect by assigning reference to a reference variable:

```
std::string& brokenRef = c->getId();
```

In addition to this, I think you mixed terms *memory leak* and *dangling pointer* (*dangling reference*). Returning a pointer or a reference of a member does not cause memory leaks. But using them (dereferencing) after object is destroyed (so memory where members used to be stored is freed and they are becoming *dangling*) causes undefined behaviour and very likely crash.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay in your example, because you assign to `string`, if you turn it into `string&` then it will be invalid as soon as you `delete c`.

(and it doesn't exactly cause memory leak).

Answer (score 0):

as long as your MyClass is not deleted the reference is valid.

or if you would have declared it as a stack variable then as long as its in scope the members in the class instance are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You will get some value but it will be some random value that as the object that contains it has been destroyed.

ideally I would delete and set that to null

so in your e.g.

```
 c=null;
```

Object Oriented C++ has same object lifetime constraints as every OO based language

The life-cycle for an object begins when it is created, and ends whenit is destroyed. In a C++ class definition, a member function with thesame name as the class is a constructor. This is a function whichis called automatically whenever an instance of the class is created. Constructorsare typically used to initialize the data members of the object to theirdefault state, but may also be used to allocate resources (memory, files,etc.). For any class, a number of constructor functions may be declared,each taking different types of arguments, providing different ways of initializinginstances. A default constructor for a class is a constructor ofthat class that can be called without any arguments. A default constructorfor a class will be automatically generated if no constructor has beenexplicitly declared for that class. A copy constructor for a classis a constructor that can be called to copy an object of that class (ithas a single argument of the corresponding type). A copy constructor iscalled when, for example, an argument object is passed by value to a function,or when an object is initialized with the value of another object. A copyconstructor for a class will be automatically generated if no copy constructorhas been explicitly declared for that class. A member function with thesame name as the class with a leading tilde (~) is a destructor.This is a function that is called automatically when the object is deleted.The destructor is typically used to deallocate any memory allocated forthe object (and may also release any other resources acquired during construction).Constructors and destructors are not required in class definitions.

There are several ways to create objects in a C++ program. One is todefine a variable as being of a particular class, either as a global variableor as a local variable within a block. When the declaration is encounteredduring program execution, space is allocated for the object and the constructor,if any, for the object is called. Similarly, when an object variable goesout of scope, its destructor is called automatically. Another way to createan object is to declare a variable that is a pointer to the object classand call the C++ new operator, which will allocatespace for the object and call the constructor, if any, for the object.In this case, the pointer variable must be explicitly deallocated withthe delete operator. The constructor for theobject is executed when new is called, andthe destructor is executed when delete is called.An object can also be constructed by the explicit use of a constructorin an expression.

When a class is derived from another class, it inherits its parent class'constructor and destructor. Parent constructors are invoked before derivedconstructors. Destructors are invoked in the opposite direction, proceedingfrom the derived class upward through its parent chain.

More here http://www.objs.com/x3h7/cplus.htm